# How can I optimize C++ for loops/if statements?

Tags: c++, optimization

Is there anyway to make c++ code run faster, im trying to optimize the slowest parts of my code such as this:

```
    void removeTrail ( char floor[][SIZEX],int trail[][SIZEX])
{
    for (int y=1; y < SIZEY-1; y++)                                         
        for (int x=1; x < SIZEX-1; x++)
        {   if (trail [y][x] <= SLIMELIFE && trail [y][x] > 0)  
            {   trail [y][x] --;                                        
                if (trail [y][x] == 0)                                  
                    floor [y][x] = NONE;                                    
            }
        }
}
```

Most of the guides i have found online are for more complex C++.

Comment: Turn on the optimizer. This is exactly the kind of code it is really good at improving.

Comment: do your indexes really start at `1`? or you don't process the borders?

Comment: The fastest code is no code, it takes zero time. So find a way to not do this. (Ha ha only serious).

Comment: "How can I optimize C++ for loops/if statements?" - `g++ -O2 -o prog prog.cpp`

Comment: Well for starters, you should use preincrement as long as you don't need the return value of the postincrement.

Comment: @olevegard I actually do this as a stylistic choice, but it's *awful* optimization advice. Even the most basic optimization (I'd say: simplistic dead code elimination + copy propagation) can remove any theoretical performance difference (in the case of primitive types).

Comment: @olevegard: with integers? it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Major problem I see is you have a cache miss every time trail[y][x] becomes 0. This is the biggest problem I see since your iteration over trail is correctly formed. If you can skip doing that(like only use trail and check for 0 instead of NONE in floor), you might see some improvements.

Comment: @olevegard **Please do not advertise that BS.** It's just **no longer true.**

Comment: that's why you shouldn't learn micro-optimizations. they get outdated.

Comment: @delnan  Ahh... Ignore my comment then. But is it in any way worse to use preincrement, or is it just that it makes no difference primitive types? All these comments seems very hostile towards my comment

Comment: @olevegard They're hostile because it's plain wrong, anyone with basic knowledge about optimization can tell why it's wrong, and it furthermore perpetuates a mindset that's harmful in the big picture by wasting engineer time on futile micro optimizations. It's not worse performance wise (both are optimized to the same machine code) but it's worse time management wise to worry about these such "minor inefficencies" to begin with, and doubly so in cases where there is no inefficency to begin with. Also, some people take offense to harmless actions being done for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Do you KNOW that this is the slow part of your code or do you ASSUME? Did you profile?

Comment: Use OpenMP to parallelize the outer for loop.

Comment: @JohannesS. Well im using a timer function in the main function to record the framerates.

Comment: @olevegard: apart from "BS", I don't see anything *hostile*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Well to me it seemed kinda hostile for something that isn't wrong.

Comment: @EJP Yeah im using visual studios optimizations, its just im trying to improve c++ code to get even faster code.

Comment: @olevegard While what H2CO3 said is true for integers, your advice does make sense if you are iterating over an stl data structure, in particular if that data structure is holding object with expensive copy constructors. In this case though it doesn't apply.

Comment: Looks like you could put your x,y coordinates and the "time" in a _circular buffer_ and process only that. Aging the buffer can also be accomplished without explicitly decreasing every item.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what kind of optimization you are seeking. Is seems to me that you are talking about a more "low-level" optimization, which can be achieved, in combination with compile flags, by techniques such as changing the order of the nested loops, changing where you place your `if` statements, deciding between recursive vs. iterative approaches, etc.

However, the most effective optimizations are those targeted at the algorithms, which means that you are changing the complexity of your routines and, thus, often diminishing execution time by orders of magnitude. This would be the case, for example, when you decide to implement a [Quicksort](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQuicksort&ei=wT_kUtK4JcuNkAfEiICgCw&usg=AFQjCNGiw1n0NOpcNK8sCU-oSo29IpT93Q&sig2=xPQwmKJvTxjS0AlrA4lRMQ&bvm=bv.59930103,d.eW0) instead of a [Selection Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort). An optimization from an O(n^2) to an O(n lg n) algorithm will hardly be beaten by any micro optimization.

In this particular case, I see that you are trying to "remove" the elements from the matrix when they reach a certain value. Depending on how those values change, simply tracking when they reach that and adding them to a [queue](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FQueue_%28abstract_data_type%29&ei=0EDkUqKsEoiUkQfopYDwDw&usg=AFQjCNGlZ7iQoiYAxztDlamhBKqI2QTxhg&sig2=Un6Cbu9K53XVrFLMSneCuA&bvm=bv.59930103,d.eW0) for removal right there, instead of always checking the whole matrix, might do it:

```
trail[y][x]--; // In some part of your code, this happens
if (trail[y][x] == 0) { //add for removal
    removalQueueY[yQueueTail++] = y;
    removalQueueX[xQueueTail++] = x;
}

//Then, instead of checking for removal as you currently do:
while (yQueueHead < yQueueTail) {
    //Remove the current element and advance the heads
    floor[removalQueueY[yQueueHead]][removalQueueX[xQueueHead]] = NONE;
    yQueueHead++, xQueueHead++;
}
```

Depending on how those values change (if it is not a simple `trail[y][x]--`), another data structure might prove more useful. You could try using a [heap](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FHeap_%28data_structure%29&ei=t0HkUpg8xsCRB7b1gPAC&usg=AFQjCNHM9BUx27Sf088myilVYxkAdimbTQ&sig2=ekqvndvXY3AwFfB4lAiwCw), for example, or an `std::set`, `std::priority_queue`, among other possibilities. It all comes down to what operations your algorithm must support, and which data structures allow you to execute those operations as efficiently as possible (contemplating memory and execution time, depending on your priorities and needs).

Comment: Exactly. Otherwise, I'm afraid he'd have to rely on micro-optimization indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to turn on compiler optimization. The most powerful optimization I know is profile guided optimization. For gcc:

1) g++ -fprofile-generate .... -o my_program

2) run my_program (typical load)

3) g++ -fprofile-use -O3 ... -o optimized_program

With profile O3 does make sense.

The next thing is to perform algorithmic optimization, like in Renato_Ferreira answer. If it doesn't work for your situation you can improve your performance by factor of 2..8 using vectorization. Your code looks vectorizable:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZEX 100 // SIZEX % 4 == 0
#define SIZEY 100
#define SLIMELIFE 100
#define NONE 0xFF

void removeTrail(char floor[][SIZEX], int trail[][SIZEX]) {
    // check if trail is 16 bytes alligned
    assert((((size_t)(&trail[0][0])) & (size_t)0xF) == 0);
    static const int lower_a[] = {0,0,0,0};
    static const int sub_a[] = {1,1,1,1};
    static const int floor_a[] = {1,1,1,1}; // will underflow after decrement
    static const int upper_a[] = {SLIMELIFE, SLIMELIFE, SLIMELIFE, SLIMELIFE};
    __m128i lower_v = *(__m128i*) lower_a;
    __m128i upper_v = *(__m128i*) upper_a;
    __m128i sub_v = *(__m128i*) sub_a;
    __m128i floor_v = *(__m128i*) floor_a;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEY; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZEX; j += 4) { // only for SIZEX % 4 == 0
            __m128i x = *(__m128i*)(&trail[i][j]);

            __m128i floor_mask = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(x, floor_v); // 32-bit
            floor_mask = _mm_packs_epi32(floor_mask, floor_mask); // now 16-bit
            floor_mask = _mm_packs_epi16(floor_mask, floor_mask); // now 8-bit
            int32_t fl_mask[4];
            *(__m128i*)fl_mask = floor_mask;
            *(int32_t*)(&floor[i][j]) |= fl_mask[0]; 

            __m128i less_mask = _mm_cmplt_epi32(lower_v, x);
            __m128i upper_mask = _mm_cmplt_epi32(x, upper_v);
            __m128i mask = less_mask & upper_mask;
            *(__m128i*)(&trail[i][j]) = _mm_sub_epi32(x, mask & sub_v);
        }
    }   
}

int main()
{   
    int T[SIZEY][SIZEX];
    char F[SIZEY][SIZEX];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZEY; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZEX; j++) {
            F[i][j] = 0x0;
            T[i][j] = j-10;
        }
    }
    removeTrail(F, T);
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZEX; j++) {
        std::cout << (int) F[2][j] << " " << T[2][j] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Looks like it does what it suppose to do. No ifs and 4 values for iteration. Works only for NONE = 0xFF. Could be done for another but it is difficult.